# Should we close a question of a non existing user?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, user-accounts

There is [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213187/john-conways-game-of-life-in-haskell) in [haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell) that was originally posted on Stack Overflow but got migrated.

The thing is, the user doesn't appear to exist or has been banned. It seems to me that the post will not benefit him since he doesn't exist.

Should we close the question, or let it languish and not pay further attention?

Comment: minor addendum to the technical side note in rolfl's excellent answer: When a question is migrated to a site where the owner doesn't have a profile, a stub is created. When the user later signs up for the target site, they automatically claim that profile stub and get all the goodies coming with it :)

Comment: They thought of everything !

Comment: Another comment on this, the user has, in fact, joined Code Review now ;-)

Comment: Related: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/should-we-retain-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-users

Comment: Obviously, if it is of general interest, don't close it.  If it looks like it would only benefit the OP, then by all means, close it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, we should not close it just because the user has not joined Code Review.

If the question is on-topic, it should be treated just like any other question. Note that questions, answers, reviews are not only for the benefit of the question asker, but also for any other people that follow along.

On the technical side, the user has not signed up to Code Review, but they are a real user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10219840/omar-kahol and are not banned, or anything.

So, you ask: *"Should we close the question, should we let it languish and not pay attention"* ... and the answer is "neither". We should review the code if we're inspired to, and vote, comment, etc. as needed.

If the user signs up to Code Review this question will be automatically attached to their account when they do.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know it worked that way... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not: the StackExchange sites are not about individual users but communities. That is, a question should never be useful only to the original poster, but to the *whole* community.

As such, it is irrelevant who asks a question. Only the quality and appropriateness of the question should determine whether it is upvoted, downvoted, closed, and so on.